# Demux simulink (select which block gets input)

Tags: simulink

I am looking for a block that works as a digital de-muliplexer. I have one input signal and one selector input that determines which line the input gets passed through to.

[image: From wikipedia]

I have looked at the demux block in simulink but it does not seem to do this:

"Demux

Split vector signals into scalars or smaller vectors."

I have also looked at "Output Switch" but this only seems to take queues as input.

Comment: The reason the block you want does not exist is what happens to the unselected output? It needs to have a value even when unselected. The Multiport Switch, Index Vector and Switch blocks are all valid blocks to select one input from many. Selecting one output from many does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve what you want with 2 multiport switch blocks and one ground block:

- Configure the multiport switch block to have 2 data inputs
- Connect your data input `in` to data input port 1 of the first multiport switch, and data input port 2 of the second multiport switch
- Connect the ground block to the other two data input ports remaining
- Connect your selector input `sel` to the control port of each multiport switch
- Connect the output of the first multiport switch block to the first of your two outputs (`O_0` or `O_1`), and the output of the second multiport switch block to the second of your two outputs.

You can wrap up everything into a subsystem and even include it in a library if you intend to reuse it in different models. I would obviously test it first to make sure it has the intended behaviour.